# I cant request if a product is available from the /products.json file of shopify

Tags: python, shopify, monitor

I'm trying to program a restock monitor. To do so I want to convert the .json file of a shopify shop, but for the available part I always get an error : (

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dhooks import Webhook
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.antisocialsocialclub.com/products.json")
products = json.loads((r.text))["products"]

for product in products:
    print(product["title"])
    print(product["tags"])
    print(product["published_at"])
    print(product["created_at"])
    print(product["product_type"])
    print(product["available"])
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valentinwestermann/Documents/La dieta mediterranea_dhooks.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(product["available"])
KeyError: 'available'
```

Comment: Use indentation or three backticks to format your code block, not html elements and block quotes. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Also, questions about an error need to include whatever  information you have about the error.

Comment: @khelwood I'm sorry, it was my first post. I hope this is better. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have a look through the JSON. The entries do not all contain the `available` key.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON structure is not quite what you might expect. `available` key is in items returned as a list from the `variant` key. So to find availability, you have to process each variant:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.antisocialsocialclub.com/products.json")
products = json.loads((r.text))["products"]

for product in products:

    print(product["id"])
    print(product["title"])
    print(product["tags"])
    print(product["published_at"])
    print(product["created_at"])
    print(product["product_type"])
    for variant in product["variants"]:
        print(variant['available'])
```

Here is the first product output:

```
4508425453643
Broken Ankle White Socks
['SS20']
2020-03-27T20:29:52-07:00
2020-03-27T20:29:52-07:00

False
```

Comment: I just did : ) Do you have any other advice regarding a restock monitor for multiple websites instead of one?

Comment: Also not every variant specifies the `available` property; only the ones for which it is false.